# Flatsome theme woocomerce mini cart with quantity instead of no of items in cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using Flatsome theme Wordpress woocommerce theme.Now i want to add no of product quantity in mini cart in header.Currently it contains no of item in added to cart.In wp-content/themes/flatsome/template-parts/header/partials/element-cart.php page i have get quantity comming for products to mini cart but on load it will load original no of item count in mini cart

```
<?php 
     foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
         $lefteye =  $cart_item['_uni_cpo_data']['uni_cpo_cl_boxes_left'];
$righteye =  $cart_item['_uni_cpo_data']['uni_cpo_cl_boxes_right'];
$neqqty = $lefteye + $righteye;
echo $neqqty;
     }


    ?>
```

[image: Mini Cart with no of item count]

[image: Before Load Mini Cart]

Answer (score 0):

theoryx268 here I also need this for one of my clients on flatsome theme.
First of all, you need to find your mini cart file then edit it. if your theme is overwriting it then go to child theme and overwrite it.
or if not then go Woocommerce woocommerce/templates/cart/mini-cart.php
its the main file you can add plus(+) minus(-) button and using default woo-commerce functions